# Azure Devops Yaml using Dynamic "each" condition

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

How do I do the condition part in the code below under "Approval_Test" stage?  I have to generate the condition dynamically , can't hardcode it due to some requirements. The stage will also be generated dynamically based on the parameters param.

"Approval_Test" stage can only be run after all solution1, 2 and 3 are finished and/or skipped

```
#azure-pipeline.yml

trigger: none

#Package Parameter
parameters:
  - name: "params"
    type: object
    default:
      Solution1:
        name: "Solution1"
      Solution2:
        name: "Solution2"
      Solution3:
        name: "Solution3"


stages:
  - ${{ each param in parameters.params }}:
      - stage: Deploy_dev_${{ param.value.name }}
        jobs:
          - template: deploy-dev.yml
              
  - stage: Approval_Test
    dependsOn:
      - ${{ each param2 in parameters.params }}:
        - Deploy_dev_${{ param2.value.name }}
    condition: |
      #The "each" below would not work and throw errors.
      and
      (
        - ${{ each param2 in parameters.params }}:
        in(dependencies.Deploy_dev_${{ param2.value.name }}.result, 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Skipped'),\
      )
    jobs:
    - deployment: Approval
      environment: 'sandbox'
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a tough nut to crack and I wasn't able to solve it with the `each` keyword, but please let me present a feasible alternative.

### Alternate solution: Job status check functions

Without your requirement of also having the skipped stages the solution would be adding `condition: succeeded()` to the `stage: Approval_Test` :

[image: stages-success]

But this doesn't work for a skipped stage.
[image: one stage skipped]

### Not Failed?

Unfortunately there is no 'Skipped' to check from the [job status functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#job-status-functions), but what if we take the opposite of failed(), not(failed())!?

The works out fine:

[image: not failed]

```yaml
#azure-pipeline.yml

trigger: none

#Package Parameter
parameters:
  - name: "params"
    type: object
    default:
      Solution1:
        name: "Solution1"
      Solution2:
        name: "Solution2"
      Solution3:
        name: "Solution3"


stages:
  - ${{ each param in parameters.params }}:
      - stage: Deploy_dev_${{ param.value.name }}
        jobs:
          - template: deploy-dev.yml
  - stage: skipped # test to simulate a skip from the template
    condition: failed()
    jobs:
      - job: concat      
        steps:
        - ${{ each parameter in parameters.params }}:
          - script: echo Deploy_dev_${{ parameter.value.name }}.result

  - stage: Approval_Test
    condition: not(failed())
    dependsOn:
      - skipped # test to simulate a skip from the template
      - ${{ each param2 in parameters.params }}:
        - Deploy_dev_${{ param2.value.name }}

    jobs:
    - deployment: Approval
      environment: 'sandbox'
```

### (Don't) use the equivalent

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#job-status-functions) `failed()` is a equivalent for `eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Failed')`.
Would `eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Skipped')` not be the solution then?
No!

[image: no]

Why I don't understand, but in my tests (above) with the yaml (below) it wouldn't fly.

```yaml
#azure-pipeline.yml

trigger: none

#Package Parameter
parameters:
  - name: "params"
    type: object
    default:
      Solution1:
        name: "Solution1"
      Solution2:
        name: "Solution2"
      Solution3:
        name: "Solution3"

stages:
  - ${{ each param in parameters.params }}:
      - stage: Deploy_dev_${{ param.value.name }}
        jobs:
          - template: deploy-dev.yml
  - stage: skipped # test to simulate a skip from the template
    condition: failed()
    jobs:
      - job: concat      
        steps:
        - ${{ each parameter in parameters.params }}:
          - script: echo Deploy_dev_${{ parameter.value.name }}.result

  - stage: Approval_Test
    condition: in(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Skipped')
    dependsOn:
      - skipped # test to simulate a skip from the template
      - ${{ each param2 in parameters.params }}:
        - Deploy_dev_${{ param2.value.name }}

    jobs:
    - deployment: Approval
      environment: 'sandbox'
```

### Conclusion

If `not(failed())` works for you, I advice you to use that.